# elasticsearch - Aggregation returns terms in key , but not the complete field, how can I get full field returned?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

In the elasticsearch implementation ,  I have few simple aggregations on the basis of few fields as shown below -

```
 "aggs" : {
    "author" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "author" 
          , "size": 20,
          "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }
        }
    },
    "title" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "title" 
          , "size": 20
        }
    },
    "contentType" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "docType" 
          , "size": 20
        }
    }
}
```

The aggregations work fine and I get the results accordingly. but the title key field returned (or any other field - multi word) , has single word aggregation and results. I need the full title in the returned result, rather then just a word- which doesn't make much sense. how can I get that.

Current results (just a snippet) -

```
"title": {
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "test",
           "doc_count": 1716
        },
        {
           "key": "pptx",
           "doc_count": 1247
        },
        {
           "key": "and",
           "doc_count": 661
        },
        {
           "key": "for",
           "doc_count": 489
        },
        {
           "key": "mobile",
           "doc_count": 487
        },
        {
           "key": "docx",
           "doc_count": 486
        },
        {
           "key": "pdf",
           "doc_count": 450
        },
        {
           "key": "2012",
           "doc_count": 397
        } ] }
```

expected results -

```
"title": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "test document for stack overflow ",
               "doc_count": 1716
            },
            {
               "key": "this is a pptx",
               "doc_count": 1247
            },
            {
               "key": "its another document and so on",
               "doc_count": 661
            },
            {
               "key": "for",
               "doc_count": 489
            },
            {
               "key": "mobile",
               "doc_count": 487
            },
            {
               "key": "docx",
               "doc_count": 486
            },
            {
               "key": "pdf",
               "doc_count": 450
            },
            {
               "key": "2012",
               "doc_count": 397
            } }
```

I went through a lot of documentation, it explains different ways to aggregate results, but I couldn't find how to get the full text if a field in key in result , please advise how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to have untokenized copies of the terms in the index, in your mapping use [multi-fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html):

```
{
    "test": {
        "mappings": {
            "book": {
                "properties": {                
                    "author": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "untouched": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "untouched": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "docType": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "untouched": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your aggregation query reference the untokenized fields:

```
"aggs" : {
    "author" : {
         "terms" : { 
            "field" : "author.untouched", 
            "size": 20,
            "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }
        }
     },
    "title" : {
        "terms" : { 
          "field" : "title.untouched", 
          "size": 20
        }
    },
    "contentType" : {
        "terms" : { 
           "field" : "docType.untouched", 
           "size": 20
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Dan!! I am going to try this, looks very promising!

Comment: how about a field, which i need to have tokenized for search query, but at the same time untokenized for aggregations?

Comment: The above mapping does that, it indexes the field using the default analyzer (Standard analyzer) and indexes an untokenized version of the field. For example, for search use the field name `title` (tokenized), for aggregations use the field name `title.untouched` (untokenized).

Comment: @DanTuffery thanks, im here again. is it possible to query the indexed field but let return the original field? more specifically, i use some asciifolding filtering on the indexed field, but need to return the orginal value. im stuck on how to do this in 1 step within aggregations. i got something like this: `"aggregations": {  "suggestion": {  "terms": { "field": "name",` but instead of returning name, i want the `name.untouched` to be returned

Comment: @ulkas You are on the right track. Your query will be separate from your aggregation.Using your index field in your query, and your untouched field in your aggregation. `"query": {...}, "aggregation": {...}`

Answer (score 0):

seems the multi_fields specified in the above post is deprecated
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html#_multi_fields

Comment: They are deprecated but the way the poster above is using it is the new way as per the link you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.
When I ran the command:

```
   curl -XGET "localhost:9200/logstash*/_mapping?pretty"
```

response had following in it which was useful:

```
   "host" : {
     "type" : "string",
       "norms" : {
         "enabled" : false
       },
       "fields" : {
         "raw" : {
           "type" : "string",
           "index" : "not_analyzed",
           "ignore_above" : 256
         }
       }
     },...
```

I realised than that adding .raw should change the output and will get the desired output.

so something like:

```
      "aggs": {
        "computes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "host.raw",
            "size": 0
          }
        }         
      }
```

Did the trick for me.

Newbie to the elasticsearch but I am seeing many field of type string has a "raw" field which can be used within query.

It would be good if some experts can shed a light on my findings. Correct/Partially correct/Wrong ?!

Comment: The logstash output plugin creates a default index template in Elasticsearch that is applied to any index that has a name that starts with `logstash-`. When this template is used a `raw` field is created by default for every property that is of type `string`. This is the template: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/v0.2.4/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json#L18-L27