# Aggregation returns terms in key, but not the complete field sorted according to sort condition

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have problem with getting distinct titles from ES 5.4. It was returning only single distinct words instead of the whole titles. I have created raw multifield like suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640117/elasticsearch-aggregation-returns-terms-in-key-but-not-the-complete-field-h). I have adjusted solution from there to  [current mapping changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html) but it doesn't work well as I get error:

"*Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [title.raw] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.*"

Field mapping:

```
"title":{
  "type":"text",
  "fields":{
     "keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256},
     "raw":{"type":"text","index":false},
     "sort":{"type":"text","fielddata":true}}}
```

Terms aggregation with query:

```
{
"aggs": {
  "title.raw" : {
    "terms" : {
      "field" : "title.raw",
      "size" : 30,
      "min_doc_count" : 1,
      "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
      "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
      "order" : [
      {
        "_count" : "desc"
      },
      {
        "_term" : "asc"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As I understand I can't use ***fielddata true*** together with ***index false***. How should look my mapping to be able get full distinct titles sorted ascending?

Comment: Why not just use a keyword field (without ignore_above)?

Comment: Thanks, it worked out!